# Possible to open a file from cmd with a specified program based on a IF?

Tags: command-prompt

Hi I am wondering if it's possible with a batch file to open a certain text file with a specific program, in my example notepad++.

This is possible using the command

```
"C:\path\to\Notepad++.exe" "C:\path\to\file\text.txt"
```

But if I was to run my batch file on a computer that doesn't have Notepad++ installed. Would it then be possible to make this into a IF statement, something like this?

If Notepad++ is installed in directory open text.txt with Notepad++

Else open text.txt in Notepad if Notepad++ is not installed.

Comment: Why not use `start` and simply launch the user's preferred text editor? `

Comment: I'm using my batch file to run a php program which output gets stored in a txt file. Windows Notepad doesn't support the line-break format the output is printed in, so the txt file is very messy if opened with Notepad. Therefore I want it to preferably open in Notepad++ so that it is shown properly. But if Notepad++ is not installed, this command will fail and the txt won't be opened during the batch process. I was then thinking to have it open in Notepad or WordPad as alternative.

Comment: If you're creating the text file on Windows, you should be using Windows CR/LF pairs, and any text editor can open them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this blog about [Windows Batch Scripting: If/Then Conditionals](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-5-if-then-conditionals.html)

Which describes the use of IF EXIST and IF NOT EXIST which can be put together to an IF EXIST/ELSE statement.

For my question this does the job:

```
IF EXIST "C:\path\to\Notepad++.exe" (
    "C:\path\to\Notepad++.exe" "C:\path\to\file\text.txt"
) ELSE (
    Start Notepad "C:\path\to\file\text.txt"
)
```